Parsing/Splitting Last Name First Name MI
I'm working on a crystal report where the user requires the physician's name be parsed/split into 3 columns:  first name, last name and middle initial.
My data shows last name [space] first name [space] mi
Looking at other similar questions, most people have symbols or something between the names to indicate the split.  The only pattern the field contains in my report is the space between each part of the name - there are varying lengths on each part of the name.
Currently, for example:
Jones Henry I
Smith Robert MD
Peabody Matt DO

I need it to split out into separate columns, like this:
Phys_Last | Phys_First | Phys_MI
Jones       Henry        I
Smith       Robert       MD
Peabody     Matt         DO

How can I do this?

Crystal provides a Split function.
So Split({NameField}, " ") would result in an array.
You can then refer to the elements of the array using the element position.
For example,
Split({NameField}, " ")[1] 

should give you the Last Name.
Consider checking the size of the array, using the UBound() function, in order to handle cases where the structure doesn't follow your expectations.
